# What did Husserl mean by logically composite?

Tags: logic, husserl

In the *philosophy of arithmetic* on page 119, Husserl says that only things that are logically composite can be given formal logical definition. He does not define and term beyond that and only gives examples of concepts that are not logically composite and thus cannot be defined. I cannot find definitions of the term by searching online and I think a clearer articulation of what he meant by that would help me understand the argument.

Comment: It means that you can compose them from other concepts using logical devices, namely propositional connectives and quantifiers. E.g. you can define "even" from 2, equality and multiplication using the existential quantifier.